# How to prove the optimality of $r = \frac{Ax^*-b}{\|Ax^*-b\|_2}$ for the dual problem of $\text{minimize}\quad \|Ax-b\|_2 + \gamma\|x\|_1$?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, duality-theorems

When I'm doing convex optimization homework, the teacher wants me to show the following problem:(I believe this should be done using duality)

> Consider the optimization problem:
> $$\text{minimize}\quad  \|Ax-b\|_2 + \gamma\|x\|_1$$ where $A\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$,$b\in \mathbb{R}^m$ and $\gamma>0$. If $x^*$ is an optimal point, and $Ax^*-b\neq0$, define : $r = \frac{Ax^*-b}{\|Ax^*-b\|_2}$.
> $$\text{Show that:}\quad\|A^Tr\|_\infty\leq \gamma \quad r^TAx^*+\gamma\|x^*\|_1=0$$

However, I don't know how the inequality and equality I need to show are related to the optimization problem... I tried to derive the dual problem of this optimization problem:

First I change it into:
$$\text{minimize}\quad  \|y\|_2 + \gamma\|x\|_1$$
$$\text{subject to}\quad Ax-b=y$$

And I derive it's dual problem:
$$\text{maxmize}\quad  -v^Tb$$
$$\text{subject to}\quad \|A^Tv\|_\infty\leq \gamma\quad \|v\|_2\leq 1$$

I can see that, if $r$ is the optimal point of the dual problem, then by the strong duality, we can show that:$-r^Tb=\|Ax^*-b\|_2+\gamma\|x^*\|_1$,which is just $r^TAx^*+\gamma\|x^*\|_1=0$. But I don't know how to show that $r$ is the optimal point of the dual problem...Any hints on how can I prove this?  Thanks!

Comment: Did you try stating the KKT conditions, use weak/strong duality, etc?

Comment: @V.S.e.H.: Actually, I've tried. But the L1 norm is not differentiable, so I don't know how to deal with that... Do you have any further thoughts?

Comment: @V.S.e.H.: This convex optimization problem has no inequality constraints, so it must be strong duality. So this means for $x^*$, there must be a $v^*$ satisfying the KKT condition. However, I don't know how to form the KKT condition of this problem because of the indifferentiable of the L1 norm

Comment: You can convert $\gamma \|x\|_1$ into a linear function, and introduce linear constraints. You can move $\|Ax - b\|_2$ as an inequality constraint (which also allows you to square it there). Then the problem becomes a SOCP (also confirmed in Boyd and Vandenberghe's book).

Answer (score 1):

I found some free time to try and solve this. Let $e=(1,\ldots,1)^T$ and rewrite the problem in the following equivalent SOCP form:
\begin{align}
\text{minimize}\quad&  y + \gamma e^Tz,\\
\text{subject to}\quad& \|Ax-b\|_2^2/2\leq y^2/2,\\
                      & x-z\leq 0,\\
                      & -x-z \leq 0,
\end{align}
where $a\leq b \iff b-a\in\mathbb{R}^n_+$.
Note that Slater's condition holds for this problem: take $x = 0, y = \alpha \|b\|, z = \beta e, \alpha > 1, \beta > 0,$ thus strong duality holds. It is also clearly bounded, so it is dual-feasible.

Write the Lagrangian as:
$$
L(x,y,z,\lambda,\mu,\nu)=y + \gamma e^Tz + \lambda\left(\|Ax-b\|_2^2 - y^2\right)/2+\sum_{i=1}^n\mu_i(x_i-z_i)-\sum_{i=1}^n\nu_i(x_i+z_i),
$$
and write down the KKT conditions that our optimal point $(x,y,z)$ satisfies:
\begin{align}
\nabla_xL =\lambda A^T(Ax-b)+\mu-\nu &=0\\
\nabla_yL =1-\lambda y&=0\\
\nabla_zL =\gamma e-\mu-\nu&=0\\
 \lambda\left(\|Ax-b\|_2^2 - y^2\right)/2+\sum_{i=1}^n\mu_i(x_i-z_i)-\sum_{i=1}^n\nu_i(x_i+z_i)&=0\\
\begin{pmatrix}I&-I\\-I&-I\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\z\end{pmatrix}&\leq 0\\
\|Ax-b\|_2^2&\leq y^2\\
\lambda,\mu,\nu &\geq 0.
\end{align}
Notice that from the second equality, $y = \lambda^{-1} > 0$, and so by complementary slackness, we must have $y = \|Ax - b\|_2$ so $\lambda = \|Ax-b\|_2^{-1}$.
We can eliminate $\nu$ using the third equality:$\nu =\gamma e - \mu,$
thus from the first equality
$$
\lambda A^T(Ax-b) + 2\mu - \gamma e = A^Tr + 2\mu - \gamma e \implies \mu = \frac{1}{2}(\gamma e - A^Tr) \geq 0\implies \gamma e \geq A^Tr,
$$
and also
$$
\nu = \frac{1}{2}(\gamma e + A^Tr)\geq 0 \implies  A^Tr\geq -\gamma e.
$$
and these two inequalities are equivalent to $\|A^Tr\|_\infty \leq \gamma$.

Also, the fourth equality from the KKT conditions becomes:
$$
(\mu-\nu)^T x - (\mu+\nu)^Tz = -r^TAx - \gamma e^Tz = 0.
$$
which is equivalent to
$$
r^TAx + \gamma \|x\|_1 = 0,
$$
after setting $z_i=\operatorname{sign}(x_i)x_i,i=1,\ldots,n$.